# How could I write the "\b" character in a file?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a file containing the `"\b"` character as a string, but when open the file it is omitted.

Here is my code:

```
with open('proof.tex','w') as archivo:
    archivo.write('''\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
$S=\sum ^{100}_{i=0}a_{i}\left( x\right) $
\end{document}''')
```

And here is the text generated in the output file:

```
egin{document}
$S=\sum ^{100}_{i=0}a_{i}\left( x\right) $
\end{document}
```

Comment: A backslash character in a string literal is interpreted as starting a character escape. If you want a literal backslash character you should probably use a raw string literal: use `r'''` instead of just `'''`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel; but that does not work inside the write method.

Comment: What do you mean? String literals work the same way everywhere in Python.

Comment: Using r''' ''' instead (as it is used with the print method) returned an error, but I could solve it using the double backslash.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. If you can come up with a [mcve] to reproduce that, please open a new question about it!

Comment: You are right; it worked as you said. I was, by mistake, leaving extra space between the r and the string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The issue is that you **do not want** to write "the \b character" into the file. "The \b character" is a backspace character, but the file **actually should contain** a backslash followed by a lowercase b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's writing the backspace character, you're just not seeing it in whatever external program you're using.

Confirmation:

```
>>> with open('temptest.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('123\b456')
...
>>> with open('temptest.txt', 'r') as f2:
...     s = f2.read()
...
>>> s
'123\x08456'
```

Try a tool like `hexdump` to look at your file and see the raw bytes. Most text editors don't display `\b` (U+0008, "backspace") in any visible way.

If you're looking to actually put a raw backslash followed by a raw `b`, on the other hand, you need to escape the backslash: Python interprets `\b` as meaning U+0008, just like how `\n` means a newline and `\t` means a tab.

The easiest way is to use a raw string:

```
my_content = r'''\b \b \b'''
```

Note the `r` (for "raw") in front! This will have actual raw backslashes followed by actual raw `b`s.

You can also double the backslash:

```
my_content = '''\\b \\b \\b'''
```

This has the same effect.